# SQL Server - XQuery - Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

What is the best way to retrieve values **A** and **B** on SQL Server?
I have the following as a part of an XML type column.

```
<Data Name=""Teams"">
         <Data DataElement=""Test"" Value=""FirstTeam=A;SecondTeam=B;""/>
</Data>
```

Is it better to substring the query result (ie use sql substring) or is it more efficient to substring the xquery result (ie use substring in the xquery)?

Thank you

Comment: While  substring  could be faster parsing xml would be more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does *as a part of an XML type column* mean?

- Your example is not valid XML (doubled `"` signs?)
- Your XML has a strange design (nested `Data` within `Data`...)

Is there a reason not to put this like (much better to query!)?

```
<Teams>
  <Team DataElement="Test" Name="A"/>
  <Team DataElement="Test" Name="B"/>
</Teams>
```

As XML has - other than SQL Server - an inherent order by position, you would not need a "first" or "second" team. Well, of courrse you can add an attribute to specify this...

If this is a snippet of a *big XML*, you have to consider, that

- *real XML* will navigate down the tree only searching for `<` which is pretty fast
- multiple occurence of your target (would this be `Value="`?) will lead to unexpected results...
- Which data type do you use for storage? Hopefully this is `XML`... For `SUBSTRING` you´d have to do an expensive cast...

So my clear advise: Use *real XML methods* to navigate to the given content and separate the content of `@Value` extra.

Try it like this to get the content:

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
'<Data Name="Teams">
         <Data DataElement="Test" Value="FirstTeam=A;SecondTeam=B;"/>
</Data>';
SELECT @XML.value('(//Data[@DataElement="Test"]/@Value)[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

#### UPDATE Use a table and split it *on-the-fly*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(YourXMLColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(
'<Data Name="Teams">
         <Data DataElement="Test" Value="FirstTeam=A;SecondTeam=B;"/>
</Data>'
);

SELECT Team.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Team
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourXMLColumn.value('(//Data[@DataElement="Test"]/@Value)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS Splitted(X)
CROSS APPLY X.nodes('x') AS The(Team)
```

The result

```
Team
-----------
FirstTeam=A
SecondTeam=B
```

(You might split this in two column again, but this is something you should solve on your own now :-).

The fact that you have to split one value to get entries you'd have to split again, shows clearly, that this is not the best design...

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! 
I know the agreed xml layout is not the best possible and I have already pointed it out to the source system that will send it to us.
XML is used for storage, so I know substring would be expensive, that's why I asked if there would be a way to do it on the xml.


Thanks for your answer once again, it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal xml.nodes to get that value from xml and then parse the value based on the requirement

```
declare @xml xml =
'<Data Name="Teams">
         <Data DataElement="Test" Value="FirstTeam=A;SecondTeam=B;"/>
</Data>'

select x.r.value(N'@Value', N'varchar(100)') as val from @xml.nodes('Data/Data') as x(r)
```